# Royal Enfield classic 350cc Gun Metal grey BS4 engine stop in between ride not with 5 liters above reserve

Tags: royal-enfield, enfield-classic

It's been so frustrating to have issues with the Royal Enfield classic 350cc gun metal grey BS4 engine. My issue is that it stops all of a sudden while riding for a little while. Most of the times it miss fires many times. Unbelievable how these guys became so successful even after so many faults. I found out a hack for this issue once the bike stops i open the petrol tank for few seconds and close it then it's fine for about 10-15 kms then again this issue repeats. Heard it's due to the new charcoal canister from a few other threads. Any idea what I should do with this issue? What should I ask the service guys to fix? Aren't the Royal Enfied guys ashamed to release a bike thats not been tested on our roads and climatic conditions and made sure it works fine?

Comment: This must be India? Producing anything to run in those conditions is a challenge for any company... Have you serviced it? Changed the fuel filter?

Comment: If it's so hard for a company this big then they shouldn't release anything here. I'm also an engineer we test out our products under every circumstances where ever we release our products.

Comment: Does true bike run faultlessly for many miles if you leave the petrol filler cap open? Do this when it’s quite empty of petroleum and you’re going to be riding smoothly with no abrupt stopping and starting, to prevent fuel from splashing out

Comment: So you don’t have a returns department or anything under warranty as your products are perfect... so you have Six Sigma AAA+++

Comment: Did you do any servicing or check or replace the filter?

Answer (score 0):

Vehicle fuel tanks have small vents, so that as the fuel is consumed and the fuel level drops in the tank, air is admitted to the tank above the fuel level. If air isn't allowed to enter the tank, the amount of fuel coming out of the tank will reduce and stop.

The behavior you describe is commonly seen when the fuel tank's vent is obstructed. You'll find a vent either in the fuel cap, or separate from the cap. Make sure the vent is operating, and that air can pass through whatever vent hose or one-way valve or other plumbing is provided.

Comment: I have seen the vents. But, how on earth can I check if air is flowing? 1st service is done. They told it would take a week for them to find out and fix. I thought I would investigate on the issue and find out what is to be fixed and ask the service guys to fix the particular problem rather than fixing the miss firing and stopping problem by taking loger than required.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with your machine, and don't know how its tank venting is arranged. I suggest you search the net for "check motorcycle fuel tank venting" for ideas on how to diagnose the issue.